# in context api i am getting value in console but not in li

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to iterate objects and want to show data in div, but i get a blank screen when I run this code. Please check and suggest what's wrong. Here is my code:

```js
/* provider file where we set state */

this.state = {
    cars: {
        1: { name: 'Honda', price: 100 },
        2: { name: 'BMW', price: 150 },
        3: { name: 'Mercedes', price: 200 }
     }
};

/* consumer code where we receive data from provider file */

{ context => {
    Object.keys(context.cars).map(key => {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(context.cars[key].name)
        return <div key={key}>{context.cars[key].name}</div>
    })
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-leakey-kh1hw) a working example. Basically I don't know what is for you `context` but in my example I used `state` initialized like your code and then, to show cars name in a div I do:

```
{Object.keys(state.cars).map(key => {
    return <div key={key}>{state.cars[key].name}</div>;
})}
```